# Help to solve a linear system of ode

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following system of ode:

$$x^\prime=y-x \\y^\prime=z-y \\ z^\prime=x-z$$

with initial conditions $x(0)=x_0,$ $y(0)=y_0, z(0)=z_0$

The associated matrix has 2 complex eigenvalues and this is my difficulty, I don't know how to lead with this. In a system 2x2 it is pretty easy, but in this case I have some difficulties. I need some hints, thanks.

The eigenvalues are $\dfrac{-3+i\sqrt{3}}{2}$, $\dfrac{-3-i\sqrt{3}}{2}$ and $0$, and the eigenvectors are $\left(\dfrac{1}{2}(-1+i\sqrt{3}),\dfrac{1}{2}(-1-i\sqrt{3}),1\right)$, $\left(\dfrac{1}{2}(-1-i\sqrt{3}),\dfrac{1}{2}(-1+i\sqrt{3}),1\right)$ and $(1,1,1)$

Comment: What is the derivative of $x^2+y^2+z^2$?

Comment: $2xx^\prime+2yy^\prime+2zz^\prime$

Comment: Yes, of course, but what does it evaluate to given your specific ODE?

Comment: @Somos i didn't get your hint. is the derivative of $x^2+y^2+z^2$ supposed to be zero?

Comment: Yes, of course. That implies that the distance from the origin squared,  $\,x^2+y^2+z^2\,$ is constant. The point is moving in a circle.

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Adding the three odes we get at

$$
x'+y'+z'=0\Rightarrow x+y+z = c_0=x_0+y_0+z_0
$$

so now we follow with the system

$$
\cases{
x'= y-x\\
y'= c_0-x-2y\\
z = c_0-x-y
}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{pmatrix}x'\\y'\\z'\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}-1&1&0\\0&-1&1\\1&0&-1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{pmatrix}$
the matrix has char poly $x^3+3x^2+3x$
solving for its roots will give you the eigenvalues and eigenvectors in your question.